# как переписать row_number() в sqllite3

Tags: postgresql, sqlite3

Допустим есть таблица

```
 CREATE TABLE random(ID INT primary key , Value INT unique )
        values 
        (1,1),
        (2,3),
        (10,7),
        (4,10),
        (5,16),
        (6,17),
        (17,33),
        (8,21),
        (67,27),
        (11,41),
        (99,25),
        (12,13),
        (13,23),
        (14,29),
        (1000,9)
```

есть запрос на postgresql который выводит номер строки и значение

```
SELECT 
  row_number() OVER (partition by 1 ) as row,
  value
 FROM
  random
```

result :

```
row value
1;1
2;3
3;7
4;10
5;16
6;17
7;33
8;21
9;27
10;41
11;25
12;13
13;23
14;29
15;9
```

нужно его переписать на sqlite3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847574/how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023292/how-to-get-rownum-like-column-in-sqlite-iphone/19199219#19199219

Comment: первую ссылку видел, так не получилось